# adding an struct instance into a dynamic array of struct objects

Tags: arrays, struct

Consider this code.

```
function getDoctorsList(uint[] memory _docIds) public view returns (doctor[] memory) {
    doctor[] memory _doctors;
    for(uint i = 0; i < _docIds.length; i++) {
        _doctors[i] = doctors[_docIds[i]];
    }
    return _doctors;
}
```

Here I am using an array of id's of a mapping and store the appropriate struct instance into a dynamic array of struct instances. But I can not execute this function. It is saying that:

> call to DogChain.getDoctorsList errored: VM error: invalid opcode. invalid opcode The execution might have thrown. Debug the transaction to get more information.

Previously, I tried pushing each items. But compiler says, it is not possible. can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to initialize the dynamic array to the required length:

```
doctor[] memory _doctors = new doctor[](_docIds.length);
```

More generally, there are 4 types of arrays:

1. Inside  functions, a static  array in memory , e.g., `type[3] memory arr;`
2. Inside  functions, a dynamic array in memory , e.g., `type[] memory arr = new type[](3);`
3. Outside functions, a static  array in storage, e.g., `type[3] public arr;`
4. Outside functions, a dynamic array in storage, e.g., `type[] public arr;`

You can `push`/`pop` only to/from dynamic arrays in storage.